# Getting a wrong shape as the train input of Neural network model (( expected shape=(None, 222, 222, 3), found shape=(None, None, 224, 224, 3) ))

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

So I'm trying to train a neural network model with the Oxford 102 flowers dataset.
but for some unknown reason, I get an error using model.fit while training the following are parts related to the code:

```py
# Define the path to the dataset directory
# dataset_dir = "/content/drive/MyDrive/jpg"

# Define batch size and image size
batch_size = 32
img_size = (224, 224)

# Use image_dataset_from_directory to load the dataset
train_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    dataset_dir,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",  # Change to "binary" for binary classification
    image_size=img_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    seed=1337,
)

valid_dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
    dataset_dir,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="categorical",
    image_size=img_size,
    batch_size=batch_size,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    seed=1337,
)


train_dataset = train_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x / 255.0, y))  # Normalize pixel values for Train dataset
valid_dataset = valid_dataset.map(lambda x, y: (x / 255.0, y))  # Normalize pixel values for Validation dataset


# Batch the datasets
train_dataset = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
valid_dataset = valid_dataset.batch(batch_size)
```

This is the output of this cell:

```
Found 8189 files belonging to 1 classes.
Using 6552 files for training.
Found 8189 files belonging to 1 classes.
Using 1637 files for validation.
```

using this model:

```py
# Model ( Sequential Model )
model = models.Sequential()

# Convolutional base ( Using Convolutional Neural network to extract information from images)
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))

# Flatten the convolutional base
model.add(layers.Flatten())

# Dense layers to extract features from CNN output
# We use a Dropout of 50% to prevent the model from over-fitting and for regularization
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(layers.Dense(102, activation='softmax'))  # 102 classes for the flowers dataset

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Display the model summary
model.summary()
```

Output of model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_6 (Conv2D)           (None, 222, 222, 32)      896       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPoolin  (None, 111, 111, 32)      0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)           (None, 109, 109, 64)      18496     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPoolin  (None, 54, 54, 64)        0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 conv2d_8 (Conv2D)           (None, 52, 52, 128)       73856     
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPoolin  (None, 26, 26, 128)       0         
 g2D)                                                            
                                                                 
 flatten_2 (Flatten)         (None, 86528)             0         
                                                                 
 dense_4 (Dense)             (None, 256)               22151424  
                                                                 
 dropout_2 (Dropout)         (None, 256)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_5 (Dense)             (None, 102)               26214     
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 22270886 (84.96 MB)
Trainable params: 22270886 (84.96 MB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
```

and this train cell will lead to the following error:

```py
epochs = 10

Train = model.fit(
    train_dataset,
    epochs = epochs,
    validation_data=valid_dataset
)
```

The error I get after running training cell:

```py
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 222, 222, 3), found shape=(None, None, 224, 224, 3)
```

I have seen some similar posts referencing the same issue but none of them got a correct or decent answer hope this one gets resolved so people use it later on.

Answer (score 0):

You should `layers.Conv2D(..., padding = 'same')` in the first convolutional layer. The default value of this layer is 'valid'. (ref -> https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/)

```
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_22 (Conv2D)          (None, 224, 224, 32)      896       
                                                                 
 max_pooling2d_21 (MaxPooli  (None, 112, 112, 32)      0         
 ng2D)
```

Comment: Hey Arturo thanks for your response I just tried this solution in 2 following scenarios.
1. The first convolution layer
2. All convolution Layers 
no difference when I checked the samples and same results as before.

This is the code I used for the first layer:


model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(222, 222, 3), padding = 'same'))